# Copy Paste in Hyper Terminal in Windows

Tags: hyperterminal

How do I copy and paste my GitHub Repo URL into my hyper terminal in Windows?

> ```
> when I press ctrl+V it shows ^V
> ```

It should have the link pasted into the hyper terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to press `Ctrl + Shift + V` to paste it. And, just for additional reference, you can press `Ctrl + Shift + C` to copy from the terminal.

Comment: Thank You its working this one Ctrl + Shift + V